# How to mock a nativeElement.focus() in Angular 4 spec file

Tags: javascript, angular, specifications

I have a method which uses an `ElementRef` which is defined below.

```
@ViewChild('idNaicsRef') idNaicsRef: ElementRef;
```

`ElementRef` then sets the focus using `.nativeElement.focus()`.

The method fails while running the spec, saying 'undefined is an object'

Comment: anybody worked on this similar behavoiur

Comment: I'm having the same issue; if you come up with a resolution please post!

Answer (score 7):

Although httpNick's answer should work, I ended up asking an architect on my team about this and he led me to a slightly different solution that may be a bit simpler.

```
describe(MyComponent.name, () => {

    let comp: MyComponent;

    describe('myFunction', () => {

        it('calls focus', () => {

            comp.idNaicsRef = {
                nativeElement: jasmine.createSpyObj('nativeElement', ['focus'])
            }

            comp.myFunction();

            expect(comp.idNaicsRef.nativeElement.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
```

This particular example would just test to see if the `focus` method has been called or not.  That's the test that I was interested in when I was testing my method, but you could of course test whatever you wanted.  The key is the setup beforehand (which was elusive before it was shown to me).

Answer (score 4):

this should work. this just creates a spy object and then you can populate it with whatever you want, so you could even check if it was called in your unit test.

```
  import createSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj;
  comp.idNaicsRef = createSpyObj('idNaicsRef', ['nativeElement']);
  comp.idNaicsRef.nativeElement = { focus: () => { }};
```

`comp` is the reference to the component you are testing.

`createSpyObj` comes from a jasmine import